# Rewrite part of url from .htacces

Tags: .htaccess

i need to redirect my old url to new url structure

old is http://website.com/mp3/song-name/

new is http://website.com/song-name-mp3-download.html

How can I do this using mod_rewrite?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteRule ^play/(\d+)/.*$ playlist.php?action=shareview&id=$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ search.php?search=$1 [L]

    RewriteRule 404.html 404.php

     RewriteEngine on
     RewriteCond $1 [A-Z]
     RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /${lowercase:$1} [R=301,L]

    <IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(php|js|css|mp3|wmv|flv|html|htm)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
    ErrorDocument 404 /mp3/404.html
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^mp3/([^/]+)/?$ $1-mp3-download.html [L,NC,NE,R=302]
```

Comment: Are there more rules in this .htaccess? What URL did you try?

Comment: this is my current file

Comment: Ah not in comments (it is unreadable), please edit your question and provide it there.

Comment: ok in your htaccess insert this rule just below `RewriteEngine on` line.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68665/discussion-between-azarudeen-and-anubhava).

Comment: can you please suggest how to convert uppercase to lowercase in httpd.conf file

Comment: is there any option without using htaccess

Comment: You can do this in PHP also.

Comment: Yes `lowercase` needs to be defined using `RewriteMap`. Also please don't change the question at this stage. If you run into problems don't hesitate to open a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68909/discussion-between-azarudeen-and-anubhava).